# Compare and display using Php

Tags: php, string, compare

I am working on a code where i am having a file.txt which is used like a database and i want to search the content on file.txt in any txt file or json file. But the problem is whenever it searches it skips the 1st line.
Below is my code.

```
    <?php 
    $gameaudiof = fopen("gameaudio.txt", "a");
    $lines1 = file("file.txt");
    $data2 = $_FILES['data2']['tmp_name'] or exit("Please select the file");
    $data3 = file_get_contents($data2);
    foreach($lines1 as $line1){
    $line1 = trim($line1);
    if(strpos($data3, $line1)){
    echo $line1;
    echo "\n<br>";
    fwrite($gameaudiof, $line1);
    fwrite($gameaudiof,"".PHP_EOL);}}fclose($gameaudiof); ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of your txt?

Comment: File format shall be helpful to answer this question. Please provide sample txt file.

Comment: the 1st line of which file is skipped ?